# DataFrame' object has no attribute 'symbol

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I wanted to create a Stock Price Prediction using Machine Learning, but this appears "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'symbol'" what was my error and how to fix it

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def prepare_data(df,forecast_col,forecast_out,test_size) :
    label = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out) #creating new column called label with the last 5 rows are nan
    X = np.array(df [[forecast_col]]) #creating the feature array
    X = preprocessing.scale(X) #processing the feature array
    X_lately = X[-forecast_out:] #creating the column i want to use later in the predicting method
    X = X[:-forecast_out] # X that will contain the training and testing
    label.dropna(inplace=True) #dropping na values
    y = np.array(label)  # assigning Y
    X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size, random_state=0) #cross    validation

    response = [X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test ,X_lately]
    return response

df = pd.read_csv("GOOG.csv")
df = df[df.symbol == "GOOG"]- "where appears the error message" 
forecast_col = "close"
forecast_out = 5
   

test_size = 0,2

X_train, X_test , Y_train, Y_test , X_lately = prepare_data(df,forecast_col,forecast_out,test_size)
learner = LinearRegression()
learner.fit (X_train,Y_train )
score=learner.score(X_test,Y_test)#testing the linear regression model
forecast= learner.predict(X_lately) #set that will contain the forecasted data
response={}#creting json object
response['test_score']=score
response['forecast_set']=forecast

print(response)
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. You are trying to access a column in the dataframe named "symbol" but there is no such column in the dataframe.

Comment: Why did you expect there to be a column named `symbol`?  Can you show us the input data?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I recommend to check the delimiter in your csv if you sure that csv contains column 'symbol'